# Recursion Help Please

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to figure out the following problem for an upcoming test. I have searched everywhere, and I understand the basics of recursion. What I don't understand for this particular question is the value of `int n` and `int k` respectively. I have the answer to this question as it is a practice question, but I have no idea how the answer was found.

```
// Precondition: n and k are non-negative integers
int f(int n, int k) {
    if (k * n == 0)
         return 1
    else
         return f(n - 1, k - 1) + f(n - 1, k)
}
```

**What value is returned by the call `f(4, 2)`?**

Comment: Just simulate it on paper (there are not that much recursions for the 4,2 case)

Comment: For problems like these, it helps to trace out what's happening on paper. Make a table with columns for n and k, and a row for each time the function is called. Track which row is the parent of which other rows (i.e., which `f` called which other `f` -- it's easy to see this if you indent each call relative to the function row that made it). You'll end up building the complete call tree, and you'll see how the values propagate.

Comment: The value returned by `f(4, 2)` is `f(3, 1) + f(3, 2)`.

Comment: Coming from a mathematics background, I'll say that being able to work such things out on paper is a VERY useful skill. Try creating a sequence of expressions that depicts the state after each call - a hint:

1: f(4,2) -> f(3,1) + f(3,2)     
2: f(3,1) + f(3,2) -> (f(2,0) + f(2,1)) + ...

Comment: "i don't understand for this particular question is the value of (int n & int k) respectively." -> n = 4 and k = 2. That's given by the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what the problem is since

```
f(4,2)=f(3,1)                 + f(3,2)
      =(f(2,0)+f(2,1)        )+ (f(2,1)        +f(2,2))
      =(1     +(f(1,0)+f(1,1))+((f(1,0)+f(1,1))+(f(1,1)+f(1,2))
      =(1     +   1   +(1+1)) +(   1   +(1+1)  + (1+1) +1 + 1 ))
      =11
```

Comment: Nice you are doing other people homework for free, I'll have you in mind.

Comment: ... hope you'll also do their later work, as a good co-worker.

Comment: SO helped me many times. I am just giving back

Comment: @MonoThreaded give a man a fish and you feed him for a day, teach him how to fish and you feed him for a life time.

Comment: SO is not about fishing, it's about the fish. Sorry ;)

Comment: [If you actually execute the code](http://ideone.com/mMy6CY) it produces a different answer.

Comment: @MonoThreaded _'SO is not about fishing ...'_ No! Not really, SO is primarily meant as a Q&A site much like a FAQ. This kind of Q&A don't fit well for the desired format. (In short it doesn't matter, if you're _giving anything back_. Answer questions not on view of the OP, but what they will provide to the community!).

Answer (score 4):

Just look at how it's called.

f(4,2) goes into 2nd block, calls f(3,1)+f(3,2)

f(3,1) calls f(2,0)+f(2,1) = 1+f(1,0)+f(1,1)=1+1+f(0,0)+f(0,1)=1+1+1+1=4

f(3,2) calls f(2,1)+f(2,2)= f(1,0)+f(1,1)+f(1,1)+f(1,2) and so on.

You should be able to work it out from here.

Comment: +1 one because you left something for the OP to do...